# Creating Expandable Grid View

Tags: android, user-interface, android-gridview

I have Bunch of images and their description as shown in the pic below. I have already done the setting up the images inside gridview. Now i want to add tap to show description functionality, I have seen many stackoverflow answers, but didn't find any concrete solution. Please help me...

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution? @Avi Patel